# C equivalent to fstream's peek

Tags: c, filestream, stdio, peek

I know in C++, you're able to peek at the next character by using: `in.peek();`.

How would I go about this when trying to "peek" at the next character of a file in C?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[fgetc](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fgetc.html)+[ungetc](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/ungetc.html).  Maybe something like this:

```
int fpeek(FILE *stream)
{
    int c;

    c = fgetc(stream);
    ungetc(c, stream);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: the conditional is unnecessary: `ungetc(EOF, foo)` is well-defined ("If the value of c equals that of the macro EOF, the operation fails and the input stream is unchanged")

Comment: @Christoph: That's handy.  My man page didn't include that tidbit, but the one I linked to does...

Comment: @emil: In C, `EOF` may be any negative integer.

Comment: @dreamlax: I understand that, but you have to represent the negative integer in some way, in binary -1 as a 8 bit character is: 0xff = 11111111. So if getc would return a 8 bit character (0x00-0xff) there wouldn't be enough room for EOF. And as it is a integer let say it is 4 characters 'a 32 bit, then any other value can be returned in the range 0x00000100-0xffffffff I.e: (-2147483648 - -1 and 256 - 2147483647)

Comment: You do need to be aware this will behave differently for blocking & non-blocking streams and whether there are characters waiting to be read or not. i.e. for a blocking stream with nothing waiting to be read the `fgetc` will block until something arrives, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a `getc` followed by an [`ungetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ungetc/)

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to implement it yourself. use [fread](http://www.xnet.fi/susv3/functions/fread.html) to read the next character and [fseek](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fseek.html) to go back to where you were before the read

**EDIT**:

```
 int fsneaky(FILE *stream, int8_t *pBuff, int sz) {
    sz = fread(pBuff, 1, sz, stream)
    fseek(pFile, -sz, SEEK_CUR);
    return(sz);
 }
```

Comment: This won't work if the `FILE*` is unseekable - for example, a terminal or a pipe.