# How to take a look at the next character in a stream in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C equivalent to fstream's peek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082743/c-equivalent-to-fstreams-peek)

Say I have a file with characters in it. I want to look at what the next character is without moving the pointer, just to "peak" at it. how would I go about doing that?

```
FILE *fp;
char c, d;

fp = fopen (file, "r");

c = getc(fp);

d = nextchar?
```

How do I look at the character that comes next without actually calling getc again and moving the pointer?

Comment: You can take a look to this question:

[Equivalent to C++'s fstream::peek][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082743/c-equivalent-to-fstreams-peek

Comment: Fair enough that this is a duplicate, but why the downvote? It's a legitimate question, and it's not entirely obvious just from looking at the C library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use `getc()` to get the next character, followed by a call to [`ungetc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ungetc/).

Update: see @Jonathan's comment for a wrapper that allows for peeking past the end of the file (returning `EOF` in that event).

Update 2: A slightly more compact version:

```
int fpeek(FILE * const fp)
{
  const int c = getc(fp);
  return c == EOF ? EOF : ungetc(c, fp);
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sure. I assumed that "peeking at the next character" implies that there **is** a next character. If that's not certain, you need an additional check.