# Check if stderr is empty

Tags: c, stderr

I write string to stderr by 
fprintf(strderr,format strimg, string)
and later from other function I need to check if anything was written to stderr.

For this matter, is it ok to just check if stderr is empty? Or maybe ferror(stderr) will do the trick?

Comment: Afaik you can't check if stderr has been written to in any portable way. Couldn't you just break out the output to stderr to a separate function and set a boolean if it's ever called?

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to use a boolean flag to track whether an error has been given or not - initialise it to false and set it to true any time you write to stderr. Then check that...

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082743/c-equivalent-to-fstreams-peek)

in the comments, there's something about EOF, too. could be exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: That's great for input files, not so useful for output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the chance, do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
char errprintf_called = 0;
int errprintf(const char * fmt, ...)
{
    errprintf_called = 1;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int ret = vfprintf(stderr, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return ret;
}
```

and use

```
errprintf("Error %d has occured!", 42);
if (errprintf_called) {
    whine();
} else {
    laugh();
}
```