# fgetc without incrementing pointer OR decrementing the fpos_t object (C)

Tags: c, pointers, fgetc

So I couldn't find the answer to this question.

Is there either:

1. A function similar to fgetc that retrieves the character at the pointer, without incrementing the pointer?
2. OR a way to decrement the fpos_t object without decrementing the pointer underneath it.**(Mostly interested in this answer)**

For C.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2082772/535275

Comment: What "`fpos_t` object are you referring to, what is "the pointer underneath it", and how are they distinct?

Answer (score 4):

You have three options:

1) use [ftell / fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/)

Example:

```
  FILE * pFile;
  char c1, c2;
  long offset;
  pFile = fopen ( "example.txt" , "r" );
  offset = ftell(pFile);
  c1 = fgetc(pFile);
  fseek ( pFile , offset , SEEK_SET );
  c2 = fgetc(pFile);
  /* result: c1 == c2 */
```

(Remark: for a binary stream, you could also try using `fseek(pFile, -1, SEEK_CUR)` but for the text mode, as it was noted, getting one character might advance the pointer more than one position).

2) [use fgetpos / fsetpos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fsetpos/)

Example:

```
  FILE * pFile;
  fpos_t position;
  char c1, c2; 
  pFile = fopen ("example.txt","r");
  fgetpos (pFile, &position);
  c1 = fgetc(pFile);
  fsetpos (pFile, &position);
  c2 = fgetc(pFile);
  /* result: c1 == c2 */
```

3) use [ungetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ungetc/)

```
  FILE * pFile;
  char c1, c2;
  c1 = fgetc(pFile);
  ungetc(c1, pFile);
  c2 = fgetc(pFile);
  /* result: c1 == c2 */
```

Which one of these methods is going to be more effective, is platform- and implementation-dependent. E.g. it could be that under the hoods `ungetc`, for example, will re-read the current chunk up to the current point. Or it could be that it simply moves the pointer in a memory buffer.

Comment: For the first example, you'd want to use `ftell` to determine the current position before the `fgetc`, then feed that back to `fseek`. Reading a single character from a text stream might advance it by more than 1 byte (for example, reading a newline from a Windows text file returns `'\n'`, but consumes `'\r'` and `'\n'`). Of course it only works if the file is seekable; you can't rewind `stdin`, for example.

Comment: Note that `ungetc()` has some interesting properties relative to the file positioning functions.  Read its specification carefully.