# Read without removing the data read from internal stream in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I want to know is there any API/system call which i can use to just read the input stream without removing the data read from input stream?

I am looking for something like `peek()` function of `arduino`. I want to use it for some socket programming (`RAW HCI socket`).

Comment: Well, you could cook up a solution around this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082743/c-equivalent-to-fstreams-peek/2082772#2082772

Comment: Maybe `tee(2)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am using raw file descriptors in Linux. Can a convert a raw fd into `FILE *`?

Comment: @abhiarora a call to `fdopen(3)` can wrap a raw filedescriptor to a `FILE *`, but if the behaviour of the resulting stream will fit your needs depends on your application (i.e. when the fd is shared between different processes)

Comment: @Ctx Thanks for the answer. It is similar to what i was looking