C: Are there ways to enter a line without using line break?
I'm working on a task and one of it's conditions is checking user input for validity. Valid input has 3 values of int type.
Here's how I deal with user input:
int x, y, z;
char ch;  

if (scanf("%d%d%d%c", &x, &y, &z, &ch) == 4 && (ch == '\n' || ch == '\0'))
    ;

else {
    printf("n/a");
    return 0;
}

This works fine for input made by humans (not really, it doesn't put out "n/a" if only 1 or 2 values have been entered), but what scares me is the automated check. Will automated check inevitably have line break at the end of input or there are other ways to enter a line?

Use fgets to read the while line, then sscanf to parse it. Or just read three integer values, and don't care if there's a newline anywhere (which the user can still put between the numbers, even with your current format).

Read documentation how scanf works. Line break is not required (you can use spaces to separate values). So your ch can contain other character (for example space) for valid input.

Try fgetc. Or you could try to look at the new character without consuming it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082743/c-equivalent-to-fstreams-peek

If number of needed inputs is small, consider using command line parameters instead of stdin. It make testing and scripting with the program easier.

It is certainly possible to terminate input without a new-line character. Automated checking software can do this by closing a pipe or redirecting input from a file that ends without a new-line character. On Unix systems, a user can send input to the program without a new-line character by pressing Control-D (and pressing it a second time would act as an end-of-file indication).
To check input for validity, you must first have a specification of what valid input is. The code in the question tests for a new-line character after the scanned int values. But what if the user enters spaces or tabs after the last int value and then presses Return? Is that valid input?
Why do you check for a null character? Null characters mark the ends of strings, but scanf is not scanning a string; it is scanning input from a stream. Null characters are not added to mark the ends of streams. They normally do not appear in input from a terminal unless a user has gone to special efforts to enter a null character. And, in that case, it would probably not be valid input; the user deliberately entering a null character does not form what appears to be intended, a line of input that contains only three integer values and separators such as spaces or tabs. So it seems inappropriate to check for a null character.
Another problem is that scanf does not handle overflow. If the characters it scans for %d represent a value that does not fit in int, the behavior is not defined. So, if you must detect overflow, then you cannot check for valid input using scanf.
Getting back to the fundamentals, you must first have a specification of valid input is. What will the checker be checking for? Was it a stated requirement of the assignment that the program must check the input for validity? What were its specifications of validity?
If it is this sentence from the question, “Valid input has 3 values of int type,” then it is a poor specification. “34 12 89 x” has 3 values of int type, as well as following text. (Not actually int type but characters representing values of int type, but people often use the language that way.) “abc 4 def 5 ghi 6 jkl” also has 3 values of int type, as well as additional text. If the sentence was intended to exclude other text from appearing, it failed. This needs to be clarified before you can write a program conforming to the requirements.
That sentence also does not say input has to be on one line. So this input conforms:

123
456


789

So why would you check for a new-line character? The sentence about valid input does not say you have to do that.


Will automated check inevitably have line break at the end of input or there are other ways to enter a line?

An automated check will commonly end each line with a line break '\n'.  It is possible that the last line will end without a line break.  Further input attempts in that case result in an end-of-file condition.
An automated check may have very long lines, or very short like "\n".  Possible, yet rarely, will a line of input contains embedded null characters.  This is unlikely for learner assignments.

To well handle all sorts of input, separate reading from scanning.
Reading: Read a line of input into a string with fgets(). @Some programmer dude.
Scanning: A useful way to parse a string is to use sscanf() with a trailing " %n" in the format.  That skips white-spaces and stores the offset of the scan, if scanning got that far.  It is also useful to test the end of the scanning - did it stop on a null character?
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Read a line of input into a string
// Return -1 on end-of-file or excessively long line.
int read_a_line(size_t n, char *dest) {
  if (fgets(dest, (int) n, stdin) == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  size_t len = strlen(dest);
  // Was the whole buffer used and without a final '\n'?
  if (len + 1 == n && dest[len - 1] != '\n') {
    // Look for additional input.
    bool extra = false;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      extra = true;
    }
    if (extra) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return (int) len;
}

int main() {
  int x, y, z;
#define INT_STRING_SIZE 12  /* e.g. "-1234567890" */
#define EXPECTED_MAX_SIZE (3*(INT_STRING_SIZE + 1))
  char buf[EXPECTED_MAX_SIZE * 2]; // Be generous, allow for extra white-spaces, etc.
  if (read_a_line(sizeof buf, buf) == -1) {
    printf("No input or too long a line.\n");
  } else {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(buf, "%d%d%d %n", &x, &y, &z, &n);
    if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
      printf("Scan incomplete or extra garbage at the end\n");
    } else {
      printf("x:%d y:%d z:%d\n", x, y, z);
    }
  }
}

